# How to pass large array from three.js to a vertex shader?

Tags: three.js, webgl

Wondering if it's possible to pass a large array into a WebGL shader, like this:

```
// array here
uniform vec3[hugeSize] arrayOfStars;

void main() {
  // iterate through the array here to compare positions with current particule
  gl_Position = ...;
}
```

I would like iterate a vector array which contains the positions of 1 million particles.

I would like for each particle to compare its position with those of the others (or a percentage of the others for better performance) in order to calculate its next position.
(I'm trying to roughly simulate a galaxy)

My problem is that I can't put an array with a size greater than 4075, while I would need an array from vec3 with a size of 1,000,000.

Comment: Put it in a texture, this is the only way if you use WebGL 1.0.

Comment: You can fit a large array inside a texture and reuse it in the vertex shader ? I don't understand

Comment: A texture is nothing more than a large array of data.

Comment: `THREE.DataTexture()` is an option.

Comment: are you sure you don't want to use attribute instead of uniform? if there is per vertex (particle) relation in your array then it would be the way rather to put it as uniform.

Comment: I got a "array size too large" when i put it as attribute :/ I'll try with texture but idk how to do it